# Spring Boot Unit Test initial part of Beans, not all Beans

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing

Suppose I have a project with many Beans. When I do unit test, I don't want to load all of them into application context due to resource inefficient. Instead, I need part of them. So, @SpringBootTest won't help.

Is there a way I can specify which Beans to be initialized in application context in unit test?

For example, I have Beans - Car and Bike defined. I didn't add @SpringBootTest so it won't load the Beans. I want to find another way to load Car into application context only.

```
public Class UnitTest {

private Car car;

// some method to get the car in application context

}
```

More complicated, suppose Car depends on another Bean Tire. I need to load both of them into the application context. One possible way is, I manually create object one by one in a Java style. Just curious does Spring provide a low granularity of Bean control.

Comment: It depends...on your configuration style ("java config" vs.+ "component scan" (vs.+ xml)) and project/package structure...

Comment: In any case, (in test) you can: 1. Use (the spring (boot) test) annotations to "compose your test context" 2. And/or *modify* this context: with an inner, static `@TestConfiguration` class 3. X/or *override* the context  with an inner static `@Configuration` class.

Answer (score 1):

@SpringBootTest has the element called "classes", which is for specified classes (Beans) to start with.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Car.class, Tire.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are planning on doing your testing you can consider using @MockBean  to Mock a particular bean you don't want to explicitly construct. MockBean reference: [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html), [example/article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean)

In this context you state your unit test needs to use Car, but for Car to be constructed Tire must also exist. If we were to mock Car, then no Tire instance is required to "use" car. Caveat being, when using mocked beans you must provide expected interactions with that bean given the method you are testing.

On the article I attached above, I would check out example 3 or 4, those seem close to your current class configuration. Lastly, Mockito library is very powerful in mocking bean/statics/spring components/pojos and verifying interactions with those mocked variables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. MockBeans require Application context as well, which I don't want to load all of the Beans. I just find @SpringBootTest can configure specified classes (Beans) to start with.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways how to do this:

1. `@SpringBootTest(classes = {Class1.class, Class2.class})`
2. `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Class1.class, Class2.class})`
3. `@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfiguration.class)`
   where

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.app.service")
public static class TestConfiguration {
    // ...
}
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-framework).